# How to access data from TextField widget from module without navigating

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

`onPressed`, of "Start Picker" button I want to get data from **`TextField`** which resides in **`blockRow.dart`** file/module. To maintain clean code, I have created module for each but don't know how to access the data.

**`TextField`** controller is created and works smoothly. No error so far in design.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r799l.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `TextField controller` in `home` page and pass it to `blockrow` throgh constructor. Also pass those controller to `buttonRow` too, then automatically when TextField get its value you can use its value with `controller.text` in `buttonRow`.

Comment: 1) Created `TextEditingCotroller`   in  `BlockRow` and also in `HomePage`. Then passed through the `constructor` from Home
2) Created the `VoidCallBack` function pointer and assigned it to the `onPressed` event of the button.
3) A  void function is created to set value which is then passed to `buttonRow` as a pointer.

Working smooth

Thank  you